# C++ Functions - Error: '0' cannot be used as a function

Tags: c++

I'm new to functions and trying to understand what I've done wrong. My build message spits out the error: '0' cannot be used as a function and highlights the line `return ((5 / 9)(fahrenheit - 32));` within the function. Thanks in advance for any advice.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double celsiusFunction(double fahrenheit);

int main()
{
    double fahrenheitTemp;

    fahrenheitTemp = celsiusFunction(99);
    cout << fahrenheitTemp;

    return 0;
}

double celsiusFunction(double fahrenheit)
{
    return ((5 / 9)(fahrenheit - 32));
}
```

Comment: What did you try to achieve by writing `((5 / 9)(fahrenheit - 32))`? Did you by chance forgot the multiplication sign i.e.: `((5 / 9)*(fahrenheit - 32))`

Comment: Also note that `(5/9)` will be 0 because it is considered an integer division. Use `(fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9` or `(5.0/9.0)*(fahrenheit - 32)` to get the right result.

Comment: Another way to say what has been answered is...there's no implicit multiplication, if that's what you were attempting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `5 / 9` is `0`, because both are integers and thus it's evaluated in integer arithmetic. Do this instead: `5.0 / 9.0` to get floating results.
2. You're not multiplying in the `return` statement, so the compiler interprets the second parentheses as a funciton call (that is, calling `5 / 9` with arguments `fahrenheit - 32`). This is of course nonsense. Do this:

   ```
   return (5.0 / 9.0) * (fahrenheit - 32.0);
   ```

Answer (score 4):

```
((5 / 9)(fahrenheit - 32))
 \_____/\_______________/
    1           2
```

2 is interpreted as a function call on 1. You forgot the multiplication:

```
((5 / 9) * (fahrenheit - 32))
```

Answer (score 3):

You've forgotten the `*` operator

Answer (score 1):

You should change `return ((5 / 9)(fahrenheit - 32));` to

```
return ((5 / 9)*(fahrenheit - 32));
```

Add `*` after `(5/9)`. 
Because of missing `*` you are getting the error.